# Expected Conditional Variance inequality

Tags: expectation, self-learning, variance

In a set of lecture notes with properties on conditional variance, I found this inequality:

```
E[Var(y|x)] ≥ E[Var(y|x,z)]
```

The intuition is clear: as you add more information, the expected variance is smaller.
However, I cannot find the rigorous derivation of the inequality.
I don't think it is a hard one, but I cannot get the trick which will lead me to the result.

Comment: Hint: $\sigma(X,Z)\supset \sigma(X)$.

Comment: Thank you, but either I don't get your hint or it sounds to me just like the intuition behind it: more info less variance

Answer (score 2):

Hint: By definition of conditional variance, it suffices to show:
$$
E[ E(Y\mid \mathcal F)^2] \ge E[ E(Y\mid\mathcal G)^2]\qquad\text{whenever ${\mathcal G}\subset{\mathcal F}.$}
$$
This in turn follows from setting $U:=E(Y\mid \mathcal G)$ and $V:=E(Y\mid\mathcal F)-E(Y\mid \mathcal G)$ in the following identity (which you should prove):

**Claim:** If $U$ and $V$ are square integrable and $U$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable and $E(V\mid\mathcal G)=0$, then
$$
E[(U+V)^2] = E[U^2] + E[V^2].
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I cannot understand it because my measure theory knowledge is quite limited. Any good reference in order to understand or an easier/different approach?

Comment: @Jack The Claim is valid if you rephrase it in terms of conditional expectations: replace conditioning on $\cal G$ by conditioning on $x$. Do you see how to modify the rest of the argument?

Answer (score 0):

This follows from the conditional version of the conditional variance formula:

Var(Y | X) = E[Var(Y | X, Z) | X] + Var(E[Y | X, Z] | X)  $\ge$ E[Var(Y | X, Z)| X] .

Take the expectation of both sides.